# Is it possible to keep bitcoind running with the blockchain synced up to only a certain height?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I am currently using `bitcoind` to do some transaction analysis on a small part of the blockchain. However, after the local copy of the blockchain reaches the `-stopatheight` value, it quits. Is there a way to keep it running at that height? Or do I need to sync the full blockchain to keep it running? I want to keep it running so that I can run the `bitcoin-cli` and perform a few RPC calls

Comment: You can use any parser for to analyze any part of blockchain that you need. For example, my script https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser can do it. If you need chainstate data, you can also calculate it from parser's output data.

Comment: @DenisLeonov Thanks for that, do you have any benchmarks? I have read in academia that Python would be slow to parse the full blockchain, have you done any sort of testing to see how it compares to parsers built with cpp or others

Comment: i think there is no need for extreme speed for onetime blockchain parsing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run with `-connect=0`. If it's not connected to anything, it can't sync further.